# I Get this error when i run mongod. Instead of getting connections available on port and i am currently using mongodb version 7.0.2

Tags: mongodb

when i enter mongod i am getting the above error, but i want to get connections available on port 27017

```bash
$ mongod
```

Output:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:49.825-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":21},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":21},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":21},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:49.827-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:50.921-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:50.923-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:50.923-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:50.923-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:50.923-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"TENANT_M", "id":7091600, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Starting TenantMigrationAccessBlockerRegistry"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:50.924-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":21760,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"CGPaari-LT"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:50.924-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:50.924-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"7.0.2","gitVersion":"02b3c655e1302209ef046da6ba3ef6749dd0b62a","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:50.925-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 22621)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:50.925-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:50.926-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"C:/data/db/","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:50.926-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=7526M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,remove=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=2000),statistics_log=(wait=0),json_output=(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rts:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:50.939-07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4671205, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This version of MongoDB is too recent to start up on the existing data files. Try MongoDB 4.2 or earlier."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:50.939-07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":4671205,"file":"src\\mongo\\db\\storage\\wiredtiger\\wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":640}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-30T23:35:50.940-07:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Comment: The error says what is wrong: `"This version of MongoDB is too recent to start up on the existing data files. Try MongoDB 4.2 or earlier.`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data directory you are trying to start the mongo instance with.If the data directory already contains files ( probably from previous 4.0 version ) , try with a different data directory path to see if the issue still persists.

Answer (score -2):

In the error logs:

> This version of MongoDB is too recent to start up on the existing data files. Try MongoDB `4.2` or earlier.

It seems that your hardware doesn't meet the requirements of mongodb and can only install versions below `4.2`.

So installing mongodb `4.2` or below will be helpful, I think :)